# Displaying an image in a gridview from an ObjectData Source created by a list(of T) in asp.net using vb

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm having a problem displaying an image from an ObjectData Source created by function which adds iems to a list(of T) class. The ObjectData Source then becomes the gridviews Data Soource. All the other fields are displaying, except the image.

Here is my code:

```
Public Class AutoDealer

Private mLogo As ImageButton
Private mComapnyName As String
Private mAddress As String
Private mContactDetails As String

Public Sub New()

End Sub

Public Sub New(ByVal Logo As ImageButton, ByVal CompanyName As String, ByVal Address As String, ByVal ContactDetails As String)
    mLogo = Logo
    mComapnyName = CompanyName
    mAddress = Address
    mContactDetails = ContactDetails
End Sub

Public Property Logo As ImageButton
    Get
        Return mLogo
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As ImageButton)
        mLogo = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property CompanyName As String
    Get
        Return mComapnyName
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        mComapnyName = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property Address As String
    Get
        Return mAddress
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        mAddress = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property ContactDetails As String
    Get
        Return mContactDetails
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        mContactDetails = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Class DisplayAutodealers
Public Shared Function GetAutodealers() As List(Of AutoDealer)
    Dim Connection As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(...)
    Dim Command As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand()
    Dim _Reader As SqlDataReader

    Command.Connection = Connection
    Command.CommandText = "Select ID, Company_Name, Physical_Address, Area_Code, Email_Address, Contact_Number from AutoDealer_Account"
    Connection.Open()
    _Reader = Command.ExecuteReader

    Dim results As New List(Of AutoDealer)
    While _Reader.Read()
        Dim _AutoDealer As New AutoDealer
        Dim AutoDealerID As Integer

        AutoDealerID = _Reader(0)

        _AutoDealer.Logo.ImageUrl = "GetAutoDealerLogo.aspx?ID=" & AutoDealerID
        _AutoDealer.CompanyName = _Reader(1)
        _AutoDealer.Address = _Reader(2) & ", " & _Reader(3) & "."
        _AutoDealer.ContactDetails = "Phone: " & _Reader(5) & vbCrLf & " or email: " & _Reader(4)

        results.Add(_AutoDealer)
    End While
    Connection.Close()
    _Reader.Close()

    Return (results)

End Function
```

My code in my image rendering page ("GetAutoDealerLogo.aspx") is working. I've tested it by displaying images on other pages. This code at the moment is getting a NullReferenceException on the CarImage.ImageUrl = "GetAuctionPageImage.aspx?ID=" & AuctionID line. I've tried various ways of getting around this but the image is still not displaying in the gridview.

Any advice would be apprecriated.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'd be better off using the Repeater control. That way, you can define the controls and the layout of each record in the bound data source. For your issue, you can add an ASP.NET Image control and bind to that. I was just messing around with the Repeater control for the first time, and I am binding to a List(Of ) in the same way, and it's a breeze to bind the data, control the layout, etc.

Comment: Thanks, I was unfamiliar with the Repeater control, so I researched it a bit, and my page is now working. The table properties also make it look a lot better than a gridview. Awesome discovery!